# Unknown External Data Source type - in Always Encrypted

Tags: azure, ssms-2016, always-encrypted

I've Created my self-signed Certificate in my local and uploaded in the Azure Key Vault.So that i can use it for my always Encrypted (column Encryption in Azure SQL DB)

Initally I experienced with [Purge issue and solved it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44657625/always-encrypted-with-azure-key-vault-ssms-purge-error/44706792?noredirect=1#comment76404109_44706792)

Proceeding further I get the Error While Performing my Encrypted Operations

This is my Log file

```
Jul 6 2017 16:01:16: Log opened. TraceLevel:Informational
Jul 6 2017 16:01:37 [Informational] WizardSummary: Message:Source database settings.

Jul 6 2017 16:01:37 [Informational] WizardSummary: Message: Source server name: xxx.database.windows.net.

Jul 6 2017 16:01:37 [Informational] WizardSummary: Message: Source database name: db.

Jul 6 2017 16:01:37 [Informational] WizardSummary: Message:Create new encryption key.

Jul 6 2017 16:01:37 [Informational] WizardSummary: Message: New encryption key: CEK_Auto1.

Jul 6 2017 16:01:37 [Informational] WizardSummary: Message:Encrypt column blobname.

Jul 6 2017 16:01:37 [Informational] WizardSummary: Message:   Table name: filenames.

Jul 6 2017 16:01:37 [Informational] WizardSummary: Message:   Encryption key name: CEK_Auto1.

Jul 6 2017 16:01:37 [Informational] WizardSummary: Message:   Encryption type: Deterministic.

Jul 6 2017 16:01:38 [Informational] WorkitemExecution: Message:Work item 'Generate new column encryption key CEK_Auto1' started..

Jul 6 2017 16:01:38 [Informational] TaskUpdates: Message:Task: 'Generate new column encryption key CEK_Auto1' -- Status: 'Started' -- Details: 'Task 'Generate new column encryption key CEK_Auto1' started ....'.

Jul 6 2017 16:01:40 [Informational] TaskUpdates: Message:Task: 'Generate new column encryption key CEK_Auto1' -- Status: 'Completed' -- Details: 'Task 'Generate new column encryption key CEK_Auto1' completed'.

Jul 6 2017 16:01:40 [Informational] WorkitemExecution: Message:Work item 'Generate new column encryption key CEK_Auto1' stopped..

Jul 6 2017 16:01:40 [Informational] WorkitemExecution: Message:Work item 'Generate new column encryption key CEK_Auto1' completed successfully!.

Jul 6 2017 16:01:40 [Informational] WorkitemExecution: Message:Work item 'Performing encryption operations' started..

Jul 6 2017 16:01:40 [Informational] TaskUpdates: Message:Task: 'Performing encryption operations' -- Status: 'Started' -- Details: 'Task 'Performing encryption operations' started ....'.

Jul 6 2017 16:02:15 [Informational] TaskUpdates: Message:Task: 'Performing encryption operations' -- Status: 'Failed' -- Details: 'Task failed due to following error: Unknown external data source type'.

Jul 6 2017 16:02:15 [Informational] WorkitemExecution: Message:Work item 'Performing encryption operations' stopped..

Jul 6 2017 16:02:15 [Error] WorkitemExecution: Message:Work item 'Performing encryption operations' did not complete. Details: Unknown external data source type.

Jul 6 2017 16:02:15 [Informational] Log Closed: Message:Job processing completed.
```

The main error is **unknown External Data Source Type**

### UPDATE

I can able to overcome this error with my other Azure DB which was **Standard Pricing Tier**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Issue solved in **SSMS V17.2**
You can download the latest version from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms)

Answer (score 1):

Did you register the Azure Key Vault provider? Did you configure the Master Key?
Please read the following article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-always-encrypted-azure-key-vault

Hope this helps.

Regards,

Alberto Morillo

Comment: Yes,i already have a azure Key Vault and i uploaded my .Pfx File which is Created from my Local machine(with the help of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ff699202.aspx) and also I've already configured the Master Key. **CREATE COLUMN MASTER KEY MyCMK WITH ( KEY_STORE_PROVIDER_NAME = N'AZURE_KEY_VAULT', KEY_PATH = N'xxxxxx.vault.azure.net/keys/yyyyyyy/…)**

Comment: What is am i missing further ?

Comment: see my Update in the above Question .Whether this will be an Issue ?

Comment: I just shared the thread with SQL Azure Team @ Microsoft. I trying to find someone with knowledge about the topic. Thank you for your patience.